# removing default document from current URL

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I use the following code to get the URL of current page.

```
thispage ="http://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL") & "?" & Request.Querystring
```

I want to check if user has typed the default document (index.asp) at the end of URL and remove it (by redirecting to the clean URL without default document in address bar).

But this code always contains the default document even when if not typed in address bar e.g. the code above returns http://example.com/index.asp when I have http://example.com in address bar.

How do I edit the above code to distinguish those URLs?

Comment: FYI the code in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44358574/893670) just removes script name, not only when it's `index.asp`. It will be problem if you use it as a shared code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a complicated task in an environment where you don't know what the applicable default document is but I think it's always `index.asp` in your case.

If so, you can do it with something like the following.

```
defaultFile = "/index.asp" ' leading slash is mandatory
reqUrl = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
reqQS = Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")

'put a leading question mark if there's a query
If reqQS <> "" Then
    reqQS = "?" & reqQS
End If

'check if URL ends with "/index.asp" (case-insensitive comparison should be made)
If StrComp(Right(reqUrl, Len(defaultFile)), defaultFile, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    ' remove from reqUrl by preserving leading slash
    reqUrl = Left(reqUrl, Len(reqUrl) - Len(defaultFile) + 1)
End If

thispage = "http://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & reqUrl & reqQS
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do soemthing like:

```
url = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
url = Left( url, Len( url, Right( url, InStrRev( url, "/" ) - 1 )
thispage ="http://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & url & "/?" & Request.Querystring
```